# Snap to grid lines when moving verticle acros the path

Tags: vertices, snapping

I need create new verticle on path in point where grid and path are crossing.

[image]

How I make it:
1. Select points
2. <kbd>**RMB**</kbd> and subdivide
3. Select new verticle
4. <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**V**</kbd> to move across path
5. Trying to move it with <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd> <kbd>**SHIFT**</kbd> and <kbd>**ALT**</kbd> modifiers

Sometimes it works

[image]

Sometimes not

[image]

How it works in inkscape

[image]

Maybe trere is easiest method?

Answer (score 0):

ok this might be a funny solution but it works!

1. your line
2. make a line with e to desired location and connect to other with f
3. do the same to other side
4. join two new verts with J
5. clean the verts with ctrl + x

[image]

Comment: Emmm... It's terrible :) There is no simple solutions or plugins for just snap to grid?..